# JHow to authentcate a user using Login and password

Tags: java, netbeans, google-drive-api, google-oauth, desktop-application

I have developed a Java desktop application which encrypts any file using AES. I have been tasked with allowing the user (any user, provided they have a Google Drive account) to upload/download a file to and from Google Drive.

I have a basic login interface as shown below. The username and password that they enter will be the same as the login credentials used to log into Google Drive. Image:
[Login Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/skThv.png)

The simple user interface will then show a list of files from the user's Google drive account folder and present it in the Jlist on the screen. There will be three buttons for upload, download or delete.

I have read a number of questions that is posted on StackOverflow and information posted on Google Developers site and I am still confused on how it all works. All I need is help from someone to please explain briefly all what is required and if I am on the right path below.

I have downloaded the Google API and have recognized that the jar files that is required are [here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/setup#generic_java). I haven't been able to get them to work fully so far.

I have managed to find the following coding (below) for OAuth 2.0 for authenticating the user in order to gain access, but can someone help me just understand this coding so I can get it to work with the 2 textfields where the user enters their login username and password for Google Drive access.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  try {
    httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
    dataStoreFactory = new FileDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_DIR);
    // authorization
    Credential credential = authorize();
    // set up global Plus instance
    plus = new Plus.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, credential).setApplicationName(
        APPLICATION_NAME).build();
   // ...
}

private static Credential authorize() throws Exception {
  // load client secrets
  GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY,
      new InputStreamReader(PlusSample.class.getResourceAsStream("/client_secrets.json")));
  // set up authorization code flow
  GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
      httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets,
      Collections.singleton(PlusScopes.PLUS_ME)).setDataStoreFactory(
      dataStoreFactory).build();
  // authorize
  return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");
}
```

This connection coding above (if it is the actual connection coding to Google Drive) is where all my problems are lying. I really do not understand it and need help in order to change it or to get it to work with the two textfields and then display a list of files on the JList from the Google Drive folder.

With this coding what else do I need to do or is needed to work with this coding? Just some basic information or steps would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is you cant.

Authenticating using Login and password is called client login, Google shutdown client login servers in May 2015. You must use Oauth2 and request access to their drive account then you will be able to access it.

Comment: @DalmTo I appreciate your response. That makes so much sense why I can't get it to work. Can you help me out, by explaining the coding briefly so that I can allow the users access to the Google Drive account. Couple of brief steps with short code snippets with definitely help me out. Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Unfortunately I am a .net programmer while I can read Java I cant code it myself.   this would probably be a good place to start https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/quickstart/java

Comment: One comment on that code the scope its using is for read only access DRIVE_METADATA_READONLY you are going to need to change it probably something like DRIVE